# Duplicate Entity error when saving db even when the database is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a MVC web app where one form affects many tables in the database. I have the page loading info into the Entity Framework, but I get a duplicate entity error when I run db.SaveChanges(). The database is completely empty so it has to be some error with the Save.

I suspect it has something to do with how I am uploading the data to the Framework, but I cannot figure out the correct way to do it.

Here is the Model:

```
public class BOGOModel
    {
        public BOGOModel()
        {

        }
        public string PROMOTION_CODE { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public DateTime START_DATE_TIME { get; set; }
        public DateTime END_DATE_TIME { get; set; }
        public int[] BUY_MEMBERS { get; set; }
        public int[] GET_MEMBERS { get; set; }
        public int PERCENT_OFF { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the Controller:

```
public ActionResult BOGO()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult BOGOSave(string MemberData)
        {
            BOGOModel ModelData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BOGOModel>(MemberData);

            PROMOTION Promotion = new PROMOTION();
            Promotion.PROMOTION_CODE = ModelData.PROMOTION_CODE;
            Promotion.DESCRIPTION = ModelData.DESCRIPTION;
            Promotion.PROMOTION_TYPESysID = 12001;
            Promotion.PROMOTION_APPLY_ASSysID = 98401;
            Promotion.START_DATE_TIME = ModelData.START_DATE_TIME.ToString();
            Promotion.END_DATE_TIME = ModelData.END_DATE_TIME.ToString();

            db.PROMOTIONs.Add(Promotion);

            AT_PROMOTION_ORG_UNIT PromotionOrgUnit = new AT_PROMOTION_ORG_UNIT();
            PromotionOrgUnit.ORG_UNIT = "150";
            PromotionOrgUnit.ORG_UNIT_TYPE = "Outlet";
            PromotionOrgUnit.PARENT_ORG_UNIT = "DG";

            db.AT_PROMOTION_ORG_UNIT.Add(PromotionOrgUnit);

            ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT AllocatedOrgUnit = new ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT();
            AllocatedOrgUnit.AT_PROMOTION_ORG_UNIT = PromotionOrgUnit;

            db.ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT.Add(AllocatedOrgUnit);

            MP_PROMOTION__ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT Map_P_A = new MP_PROMOTION__ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT();
            Map_P_A.PROMOTION = Promotion;
            Map_P_A.ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT = AllocatedOrgUnit;

            db.MP_PROMOTION__ALLOCATED_ORG_UNIT.Add(Map_P_A);

            PROMOTION_RULE BuyRule = new PROMOTION_RULE();
            BuyRule.TARGET_TYPESysID = 1;
            BuyRule.TARGET = 1;

            db.PROMOTION_RULE.Add(BuyRule);

            AT_PROMOTION_SET BuySetAttributes = new AT_PROMOTION_SET();
            BuySetAttributes.name = "Buy";
            BuySetAttributes.type = "BENEFIT";
            BuySetAttributes.PROMOTION_SELECTIONSysID = 1;

            db.AT_PROMOTION_SET.Add(BuySetAttributes);

            PROMOTION_SET BuySet = new PROMOTION_SET();
            BuySet.AT_PROMOTION_SET = BuySetAttributes;

            db.PROMOTION_SET.Add(BuySet);

            foreach(int upc in ModelData.BUY_MEMBERS)
            {
                AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE MemberValue = new AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE();
                MemberValue.KEY_VALUE = upc;

                db.AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE.Add(MemberValue);

                PROMOTION_MEMBER Member = new PROMOTION_MEMBER();
                Member.LK_KEY_TYPE = db.LK_KEY_TYPE.Where(Type => Type.KEY_TYPESysID == 1).First();
                Member.AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE = MemberValue;

                db.PROMOTION_MEMBER.Add(Member);

                MP_PROMOTION_SET__PROMOTION_MEMBER Map_S_M = new MP_PROMOTION_SET__PROMOTION_MEMBER();
                Map_S_M.PROMOTION_SET = BuySet;
                Map_S_M.PROMOTION_MEMBER = Member;

                db.MP_PROMOTION_SET__PROMOTION_MEMBER.Add(Map_S_M);
            }

            PROMOTION_RULE GetRule = new PROMOTION_RULE();
            GetRule.TARGET_TYPESysID = 1;
            GetRule.TARGET = 1;
            GetRule.BENEFIT_TYPESysID = 5;
            GetRule.BENEFIT = ModelData.PERCENT_OFF;

            db.PROMOTION_RULE.Add(GetRule);

            AT_PROMOTION_SET GetSetAttributes = new AT_PROMOTION_SET();
            GetSetAttributes.name = "Get";
            GetSetAttributes.type = "TARGET";
            GetSetAttributes.PROMOTION_SELECTIONSysID = 1;

            db.AT_PROMOTION_SET.Add(GetSetAttributes);

            PROMOTION_SET GetSet = new PROMOTION_SET();
            GetSet.AT_PROMOTION_SET = GetSetAttributes;

            db.PROMOTION_SET.Add(GetSet);

            foreach (int upc in ModelData.GET_MEMBERS)
            {
                AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE MemberValue = new AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE();
                MemberValue.KEY_VALUE = upc;

                db.AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE.Add(MemberValue);

                PROMOTION_MEMBER Member = new PROMOTION_MEMBER();
                Member.LK_KEY_TYPE = db.LK_KEY_TYPE.Where(Type => Type.KEY_TYPESysID == 1).First();
                Member.AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE = MemberValue;

                db.PROMOTION_MEMBER.Add(Member);

                MP_PROMOTION_SET__PROMOTION_MEMBER Map_S_M = new MP_PROMOTION_SET__PROMOTION_MEMBER();
                Map_S_M.PROMOTION_SET = GetSet;
                Map_S_M.PROMOTION_MEMBER = Member;

                db.MP_PROMOTION_SET__PROMOTION_MEMBER.Add(Map_S_M);
            }

            MP_PROMOTION__PROMOTION_SET Buy_Map_P_S = new MP_PROMOTION__PROMOTION_SET();
            Buy_Map_P_S.PROMOTION = Promotion;
            Buy_Map_P_S.PROMOTION_SET = BuySet;

            db.MP_PROMOTION__PROMOTION_SET.Add(Buy_Map_P_S);

            MP_PROMOTION__PROMOTION_SET Get_Map_P_S = new MP_PROMOTION__PROMOTION_SET();
            Get_Map_P_S.PROMOTION = Promotion;
            Get_Map_P_S.PROMOTION_SET = GetSet;

            db.MP_PROMOTION__PROMOTION_SET.Add(Get_Map_P_S);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json("success");
        }
```

Here is the View:

```
@model Promotion_Generator.Models.BOGOModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Buy One Get One";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2><b>Buy One Get One Free</b></h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class = "control-label col-md-2"><b>Promotion Code</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10 PC">
                <input type="text" name="f-Promotion-Code" class="form-control f-Promotion-Code01" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Description</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10 Desc">
                <input type="text" name="f-Description" class="form-control f-Description01" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Start Date Time</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10 SDT">
                <input type="datetime" name="f-Start-Date-Time" class="form-control f-Start-Date-Time01" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>End Date Time</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10 EDT">
                <input type="datetime" name="f-End-Date-Time" class="form-control f-End-Date-Time01" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Percent Off</b></p>
            <div class="col-md-10 PO">
                <input type="number" name="f-Percent-Off" class="form-control f-Percent-Off01" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <h3><b>Buy Products</b></h3>
            <table class="table" id="buytable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product UPC</th>
                        <th />
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-buy">
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" name="f-upc" class="form-control f-upc01" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm classBuyAdd">Add More</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
            <h3><b>Get Products</b></h3>
            <table class="table" id="gettable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product UPC</th>
                        <th />
                        <th />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="data-get">
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" name="f-upc" class="form-control f-upc01" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm classGetAdd">Add More</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Home", "Index", "Home")
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".classBuyAdd", function () {
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-buy">' +
                    '<td><input type="number" name="f-upc' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-upc01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#buytable').append(contactdiv);
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".classGetAdd", function () {
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-get">' +
                    '<td><input type="number" name="f-upc' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-upc01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#gettable').append(contactdiv);
            });
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
        function getAllData() {
            var data = [];
            $('div.PC').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-Promotion-Code01').val();
                data.push(upc);
            });
            $('div.Desc').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-Description01').val();
                data.push(upc);
            });
            $('div.SDT').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-Start-Date-Time01').val();
                data.push(upc);
            });
            $('div.EDT').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-End-Date-Time01').val();
                data.push(upc);
            });
            var UPC1 = []
            $('tr.data-buy').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-upc01').val();
                UPC1.push(upc);
            });
            var UPC2 = [];
            $('tr.data-get').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-upc01').val();
                UPC2.push(upc);
            });
            $('div.PO').each(function () {
                var upc = $(this).find('.f-Percent-Off01').val();
                data.push(upc);
            });
            var alldata = {
                'PROMOTION_CODE': data[0],
                'DESCRIPTION': data[1],
                'START_DATE_TIME': data[2],
                'END_DATE_TIME': data[3],
                'BUY_MEMBERS': UPC1,
                'GET_MEMBERS': UPC2,
                'PERCENT_OFF': data[4],
            }
            console.log(alldata); 
            return alldata;
        }
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var data = JSON.stringify(getAllData());
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'BOGOSave',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'MemberData': data }),
                success: function () {
                    alert("Data Added Successfully");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error while inserting data");
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit 1: Here is the specific error message:
{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__AT_PROMO__36BD5C21B6ADDCDF'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE'. The duplicate key value is (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

The schema is way to large to fit in this post, but here is the table mentioned in the error:

```
CREATE TABLE [AT_PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUE] (
  [PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUESysID] int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  [KEY_VALUE] bigint NOT NULL,
  [sku] varchar(MAX) NULL,
  [owner] varchar(10) NULL,
  [owner_type] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [LK_OWNER_TYPE] ([OWNER_TYPESysID]) NULL,
  [product_group_type] varchar(10) NULL
);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error message?

Comment: One more thing that's needed is the DB schema, more specifically - list of tables with their respective primary keys. The problem you're facing occurs when you're trying to run `db.SaveChanges()` on a context where you have added more than one object with the same primary key, but from your code it's very hard to tell which specific object type is erroring out.

Comment: I updated the post to include what you need. If you need anything else let me know

Comment: I don't see that you fill the [PROMOTION_MEMBER_KEY_VALUESysID ]in the code, and it is not auto increment ?

Comment: How would I set it to auto increment

Comment: @Max depends on your database provider. It might be enough to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to your primary key in the model, but in some case you might need to manually create a respective migration (if you're using migrations) or update the database directly with `ALTER TABLE`. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) for more info.

Comment: It looks like the only way to add auto increment is to add it to the schema and recreate the database. I am doing that rn. I will get back to you when I finish

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed the problem. It turns out that I didn't auto increment the primary key and since I wasn't manually setting it either it was always 0. Even though there wasn't anything in the database it still couldn't insert because I was trying to create two items and they had the same ID. Thanks to the comments that helped to figure this out.